# How to avoid race condition with multiple async NSURLSessions returning at the same time

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I am downloading data from a cloud API, and the API is structured so that I download several "pages" of data, for example items 1-100 and then 101-200 etc, so the flow of the code is as follows

1. Call API that tells us how many pages we need to download
2. For each page send an API call using NSURLSession
3. When each call returns update a counter so that we know when they are all done
4. When the counter reaches the answer from step 1, we send a notification to the GUI that all downloads are done and update GUI accordingly

My problem is that I am ending up in a race condition and it seems that several API calls are updating my counter at the same time thus causing it to not be correct.

Here is my code that handles the updating the counter and then sends the Notification

```
+ (void) fcFoundProductNumber:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"%s entered", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }

    NSMutableArray *fcVariants = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    int numberOfPages = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"fcNumberOfPages"] intValue];
    int loopCounter = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"loopCounter"] intValue] + 1;
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:loopCounter] forKey:@"loopCounter"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"%s \r\nnumberOfPages = %d\r\nloopCounter = %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, numberOfPages, loopCounter);
    }

    if(numberOfPages == loopCounter) {
        if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"%s numberOfPages == loopCounter\r\nnumberOfPages = %d\r\nloopCounter = %d", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, numberOfPages, loopCounter);
        }

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        NSArray *fcProduct = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"fcProduct"];
        [userDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"loopCounter"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

        for(NSDictionary *fcVariant in fcProduct) {
            NSMutableDictionary *fcVariantRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSArray *fcVariantSwatches = fcVariant[@"availableSwatches"];
            NSDictionary *fcVariantSwatch = [fcVariantSwatches objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *activityArticleNumber = fcVariant[@"activityArticleNumber"];
            NSString *colourDescription = fcVariant[@"colourDescription"];
            NSString *name = fcVariant[@"name"];
            NSString *price = fcVariant[@"priceInfo"][@"price"];
            NSString *onSale = fcVariant[@"priceInfo"][@"onSale"];
            NSString *formattedPrice = fcVariant[@"priceInfo"][@"formattedPrice"];
            NSString *primaryImage = fcVariant[@"primaryImage"][@"url"];
            NSString *stockState = fcVariant[@"stockState"];
            NSString *variantSwatch = fcVariantSwatch[@"fabricUrl"];

            [fcVariantRow setObject:activityArticleNumber forKey:@"fcVariantItemId"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:colourDescription forKey:@"fcVariantColourDescription"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:name forKey:@"fcVariantName"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:price forKey:@"fcVariantPrice"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:onSale forKey:@"fcVariantOnSale"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:formattedPrice forKey:@"fcVariantFormattedPrice"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:primaryImage forKey:@"fcVariantImageUrl"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:stockState forKey:@"fcVariantStockState"];
            [fcVariantRow setObject:variantSwatch forKey:@"fcVariantSwatch"];

            [fcVariants addObject:fcVariantRow];
        }
        [userDefaults setObject:fcVariants forKey:@"fcVariants"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fcVariantsDone" object:nil];
    }
}
```

And here is the debug that illustrates the problem

```
2017-12-20 19:33:52.504312+0800 NWMPos[29258:18702451] +[FullWebServices fcFoundProductNumber:] entered
2017-12-20 19:33:52.507301+0800 NWMPos[29258:18701949] +[FullWebServices fcFoundProductNumber:] entered
2017-12-20 19:33:52.507203+0800 NWMPos[29258:18701928] +[FullWebServices fcFoundProductNumber:] entered
2017-12-20 19:33:52.509736+0800 NWMPos[29258:18702451] +[FullWebServices fcFoundProductNumber:] 

numberOfPages = 3

loopCounter = 1
2017-12-20 19:33:52.512614+0800 NWMPos[29258:18701949] +[FullWebServices fcFoundProductNumber:] 

numberOfPages = 3

loopCounter = 2
2017-12-20 19:33:52.512614+0800 NWMPos[29258:18701928] +[FullWebServices fcFoundProductNumber:] 

numberOfPages = 3

loopCounter = 2
```

As you can see from the top 3 rows I am sending out 3 API calls and 3 are returning, but the last 2 seem to be returning at the same time and as you can see that causes the counter not to be updated.

How can I avoid this race condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach sounds fragile to me.  Here are some suggestions for improvements (including fixing this bug):

- You should not under any circumstances use `NSUserDefaults` for something that changes frequently.  `NSUserDefaults` writes data to disk.  You're abusing the flash storage on the device by doing that.
- You should not be counting.  You should be storing state in a mutable dictionary with the page number as the key, e.g.

  ```
  @synchronized(self) {
    self.pageDictionary[@(pageNumber)] = pageData;
  }
  ```

  Then `self.pageDictionary.count` is the number of pages retrieved to date.  The `@synchronize` block around the set is because NSMutableDictionary isn't fully async-safe.  You could wrap that around your math and it *might* work, but it's still a bad idea for the reasons previously mentioned.
- The dictionary approach also has the benefit of letting you retry intelligently when (not if) network errors cause some of those loads to fail.
- You probably shouldn't need to wait for the whole doc to be ready to make things available.  If a page isn't ready, wait for it and render a blank page.  You can tell if the page is ready by checking the dictionary.
- If you really do need to wait for everything to be ready for some odd reason, use a dispatch group, e.g.

  ```
  @implementation foo {
    dispatch_group_t _syncGroup;
  }

  - (...)init {
    _syncGroup = dispatch_group_create();
  }

  - (...)startTask... {
    ...
    dispatch_group_enter(_syncGroup);
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [NSURLSessionDataTask dataTaskWithURL:...
                                                     completionHandler:^{
      dispatch_group_leave(_syncGroup);
    }];
    [task resume];
    dispatch_group_notify(_syncGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
      [self allTasksFinished];
    });
  }

  - (void)allTasksFinished {
    // When we get here, the dispatch group went empty.
  }
  ```

  and when allTasksFinished is called, check and see if the count matches, then retry any failed page loads.